# How to overload general broadcasting for a custom type?

Tags: multidimensional-array, julia

I have a custom type for which I think broadcasting syntax would make sense; essentially just a wrapper around a float with different semantics:

```
struct Foo{T<:AbstractFloat} <: AbstractFloat
    content::T
end
```

Usually one would operate on this using provided overloads for certain functions, like `Base.:+`, preserving the semantics, but I want to also allow working directly with the inner value with arbitrary functions -- hence broadcasting.

How does one implement general broadcasting for such a custom type, with arbitrarily many arguments, including scalars?   Is it documented anywhere?  I have looked at the relevant code of [ApproxFun.jl](https://github.com/JuliaApproximation/ApproxFun.jl/blob/3543a16b688fa91e9a1598e1bde1edf16b5acdae/src/Fun/Fun.jl#L529) and [Nullables.jl](https://github.com/JuliaArchive/Nullables.jl/blob/master/src/nullable.jl#L411), but can't really figure out what to do. They contain a lot of style and type specifications, but the actual `broadcast` overloads aren't very understandable to me.

Comment: Customizing broadcasting is something that is completely rewritten, and much simpler, in Julia v0.7 and above. The new docs for this is pretty good, have a look: https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/interfaces/#man-interfaces-broadcasting-1. The following blog post is also interesting https://julialang.org/blog/2018/05/extensible-broadcast-fusion and obligatory link to the PR that implemented it https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/26891

Comment: I agree, just wait and do it on v0.7/v1.0. It's hard to do on v0.6 but much easier in Julia's v1.0, which will stay around longer anyways. So wait about 3 months.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that explains everything. Then please come back in three months to write an answer, too ;)

Comment: Actually, I think broadcasting is a red herring here — once you define the scalar behaviors then broadcast should "just work" on both 0.6 and 0.7 without any broadcast-specific trickery.  The hard part is defining those scalar behaviors (in particular promotion).